# TSQL join query

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis

```
Employee Table:
Empid   FNAme           LName      Hair Race
1       john            adam       1     1
2       clift           susanne    2     3

Code Table:
code  type    description
1     hair    black
2     hair    brown
1     race    black
3     race    white
```

We need to get the output data as `empid, Fname, Lname, Hair, Race` ; 
where the `hair` and `race` are not displayed as code but description form the code table.

I am beginner to sql.Can you please help to write a query 
I am not getting an expected output per below query

```
select E.Empid,E.FName,E.Lname,c.description as Hair,c.description as race
From Employee2 E  inner join code c
on (c.code = E.Hair )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be joining your code table twice:

- once to get the Hair
- once to get the race

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT E.EmpID
       , E.FName
       , E.LName
       , c1.Description AS Hair
       , c2.Description AS Race
FROM   Employee E
       INNER JOIN Code c1 ON c1.Code = e.Hair AND c1.type = 'hair'
       INNER JOIN Code c2 ON c2.Code = e.Race AND c2.type = 'race'
```

*Note that if either one of them could be `NULL`, you would want to change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`*

---

Said that, I would suggest you to **create a seperate code table for Hair and Race**.

Trying to dump everything into one code table is only confusing people and forces you to write suboptimal queries at best. You force yourself to add the type to the code table and to every join you will ever create.

A better alternative would be

```
Employee Table:
Empid   FNAme           LName      Hair Race
1       john            adam       1     1
2       clift           susanne    2     3

HairCode Table:
code  description
1     black
2     brown

RaceCode Table:
1     black
3     white
```

and simplify your statement to

```
SELECT E.EmpID
       , E.FName
       , E.LName
       , c1.Description AS Hair
       , c2.Description AS Race
FROM   Employee E
       INNER JOIN HairCode c1 ON c1.Code = e.Hair 
       INNER JOIN RaceCode c2 ON c2.Code = e.Race
```

You will get a better performance and a smaller footprint for free.

Comment: Thanks Lieven,  I am getting expected result with the second approach but when i use one code table that includes description of both hair & race i am not getting expected records.

Comment: @David - An error in my statement. I used `c1.type = 'race'` instead of `c2.type = 'race'` *(another reason to use two tables :)*. I have fixed my answer. You can try it out [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/71491)

Comment: @Lieven: And also another reason to use more meaningful aliases! :) At least, `ch` instead of `c1` and `cr` instead of `c2` *might* make that mistake less probable. But I'm just nagging, besides, I'm actually guilty myself. :) +1 for a good solution and a really good suggestion.

Comment: @AndriyM - I know, I've upvoted Sangha's answer for exact that reason <g>. In my defense, I copied the code from the original query where both tables were named `Code` and didn't bother to rename the aliases. Unfortunatly, those things always tend to bite you in the <curseword> sooner or later :)

Answer (score 2):

You can join twice to get the data you need

```
select E.Empid, E.FName, E.Lname, hair.description as Hair, race.description as race 
From Employee2 E  
inner join code hair on (hair.code = E.Hair and hair.type = 'hair' ) 
inner join code race on (race.code = E.Race and race.type = 'race')
```

Comment: You also forgot to add the `type` to your join condition.